# DaVinci Resolve 16 node causing weird artififact to text

Tags: davinci-resolve

I was following the steps mentioned in an answer about adding blur to text from [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22452/27444)

Everything worked fine but Step 10 caused a weird artifact to the text in the compound clip. The step says:

> wire the RGB output of node 02 into the master RGB output

Here's how the current node structure looks after doing everything. Notice how the text looks weirdly bold.

[image: Artifact in text]

This is how it looks if I skip Step 10:

[image: Without step 10]

**What is creating this and how to fix it? Any other way of adding animated blur to text?**

Comment: Hi.  It's my answer you're asking about.  I can't reproduce your results, but I do know that there was a bug in previous versions of resolve where ACES color management would mess up text.  Are you using ACES by any chance?  In more recent versions, they've added "smarts" to the behavior of alpha channels on the edit page, so that changing any transform parameter automatically punches out the image.

Comment: So, try re-setting transform in the inspector of the edit page (counter-clockwise arrow next to "transform") and see if it cleans up your text.  In your bottom image, since the green RGB connector isn't plugged into the color output, it's basically set to "passthrough," using the original color information of the text (which is white in this case, and you won't be able to change by changing the generator color in node 03, but should be able to by changing the text color on the edit page), so the only thing your node tree is contributing is control over the alpha channel (i.e., blur).

Comment: I'll try the reset. All I needed was a slow blur animation on the text, which is why I followed the steps in your answer. Although, I was running out of time so I left out the text animation altogether. Will report back once I try resetting transform